# What does the access_token in the following Facebook graph request means, and how to get it?

Tags: ios, facebook

I want to show the list photo's or album's of a Facebook user in my iPhone app, where in he should be able to save those photo's to photo gallery. I found some examples for PHP but unable to reproduce the same in iPhone `ASIRequest`. I want to use following graph request so how do I the `access_token` in session object.

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=   //GraphRequest
// This is the delegate I end up with after the user login, currently I'm querying some fql, 

- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    _label.text = @"";
      NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select uid,name from user where uid == %lld", session.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
}
```

Or is there any work around to meet my requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first authenticate which will get you the access code. You then use that access code for subsequent communication.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: I authenticate the user using lo-gin dialogue the above - (void)session: didLogin: is the call back method after the successful login of the user.